# Manually config message dispatcher

Tags: symfony, amqp, symfony-messenger

For reasons I want to dispatch a message to an AMQP queue, but I can't use the messenger config. My service needs to dispatch to various queues, setting the config for each one is not a viable uption as can change a lot, requiring me to update the source code every new message type. It will become a central micro-service.

Basically I want something like this:

```php
$queue = 'not-found-in-messenger-yaml'; // Or a full queue like amqp://x:y@host.com/queue-name
$payload = ['foo'=>'bar']; // or as json, or ... doesnt really matter, I can make this work

$envelope = new Envelope((object)$payload);
$messageBus->dispatchMessage($envelope, $queue);
```

That way I can change/set the `$queue` on the fly. But the `$payload` is not a class the `messenger.yaml` knows about, so I get a `No handler for message "stdClass"`.

**I have tried**

```php
$array = (object)['random' => 'data'];
$envelope = new Envelope($array);

$envelope2 = $this->dispatchMessage($envelope, [
    new BusNameStamp('non-existentA'),
    new TransportMessageIdStamp('non-existentB')
]);
```

But to no avail. I'm not new to queues perse, but the Symfony messenger works like a charm, so I normally dont need to do work like this.

I'm currently trying to create config on-the-fly, but in Sym4.4 this isn't the easiest to do (we're working on upgrading, but legacy).

Comment: What's your approach for creating the configuration? On a quick glance over the messenger code, looks like it should be doable with custom [`SenderLocator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Messenger/Transport/Sender/SendersLocator.php) and `MessageSubscriberInterface`, but I don't really know how are you routing your messages.

Comment: Hm, I've been aproaching this via Stamps, I might look into this monday, thanks. It does exception a `Invalid senders configuration: sender "%s" is not in the senders locator`, but we'll see.

Comment: The [`SendMessageMiddleware`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/28a8830602e65fe31e0fed2a5fb9b7a74b206245/src/Symfony/Component/Messenger/Middleware/SendMessageMiddleware.php) receives a `SenderLocator` as an argument. By overriding the service with the custom `Locator` _I'd say_ that you _should_ be able to dynamically load your dsn => message map and the `TransportFactories` _should_ take care of the rest. Notice the heavy use of conditionals as it's something I haven't done myself. But I'd interested in hearing how it goes! Best of luck!

Comment: I've found a pullrequest with the target for Sym6.2 (nov30, 2022). For now I'm going to leave it at that, I have time to wait :) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/39306